# $_SESSION start value and avoid negative values

Tags: php, session-variables

The purpose of the script is to:

1. Have a counter that starts at value 3 and decreases the counter per each time the web browser is reloaded.
2. Avoid that the counter gets negative values, the lowest acceptable value of `$_SESSION` should be `[0]`.

**Questions:**

1. When running the script, the counter starts at 2, why?
2. The first block-of-code in the if-statement has the role of continuously check if the `$_SESSION` is equal to `0` or below `0`. It only stops when it has reached `[-1]`, why does it not stop at value `0`.

```
<?php
session_name();
session_start();

$count = $_SESSION["count"] ?? 3;

if($_SESSION["count"] >= 0) {
  $_SESSION["count"] = --$count;
} else {
  echo("<br><br>");
  echo("Value is lower then 0.");
}    
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: I believe it's because you are pre-decrementing instead of $count++

Comment: You sent count to 3 and then immediately reduce it by one when you set the session variable.

Comment: @Dave so I would have to set the count to 4 to get the first value (of print_r in browser) to 3 ?

Comment: That is one solution yes.

Comment: You could just skip the check if session count is not set.  This is one case where I think your use of a local variable and the null coalescing operator is confusing.

Comment: After 0 should it reset to 3 or stay at 0 forever?

Comment: @AbraCadaver It should stay at 0 until user might "restart" the game and get 3 more attempts.

Comment: Just a note: DO NOT USE THIS for limiting access to a website. Use the clients IP address or /24 space of it to be sure. Cookies can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. It starts at 2 because on your first iteration `$_SESSION['count']` is not set. When it hits `$_SESSION["count"] = --$count;`,  `$_SESSION['count']` is set to `2`. You have to ensure `$_SESSION['count']` is set.
2. You must change the if condition to equal `if($_SESSION["count"] > 0)` so it will stop at `0` as opposed to `-1`.

```
<?php
session_name();
session_start();
//unset($_SESSION["count"]);return;
if(!isset($_SESSION["count"])){
  $_SESSION["count"] = 3;
}
$count =$_SESSION["count"];

print_r("Count(1): {$_SESSION["count"]}");

if($_SESSION["count"] > 0) {
  $_SESSION["count"] = --$count;
} else {
  echo("<br><br>");
  echo("Value is lower then 0.");
}    

print_r("Count(2): {$_SESSION["count"]}");
```